# How to configure logging inside a Docker container?

Tags: debian, syslog, docker, rsyslog, container

I was trying to dockerize (into Debian 8.2) an OpenVPN server (yes, I do know, there already are such containers) but something went wrong inside the container and the server failed to start.

I decided to inspect logs but `/var/log/syslog` (OpenVPN logs here on my host machine) was missing inside the container.

I thought that `rsyslog` was not istalled and added its installation before OpenVPN installation to the Dockerfile. But this had no effect, the `syslog` was still missing.

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM debian:8.2
USER root
EXPOSE 53/udp
EXPOSE 1194/udp
EXPOSE 443/tcp
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y rsyslog
RUN apt-get install -y openvpn
# ...
# Some configuration stuff
# ...
ENTRYPOINT service openvpn start && sh
```

The questions are:

- Why does OpenVPN logs to `syslog` after default installation on my host Debian 8.2 and doesn't do it inside a container? I didn't configure anything on my host machine to force OpenVPN log to `syslog`. It was a default behavior.
- How do I configure logging of the OpenVPN server running inside a docker container?

Answer (score 3):

OpenVPN wouldn't start with that Dockerfile because there's nothing to start it :-).  Your entrypoint is `sh`; that's all it will run.

If you want to start two daemons inside Docker, your entrypoint needs to be a program that starts both of them.  A lot of people use `supervisord` for this.  Note that Docker is relatively opinionated software, and running multiple daemons in one container is not considered idiomatic.

If this is just about debugging, there's no problem.  Just don't run `openvpn` with `--daemon` or `--log`.  It will write to stdout (allegedly, though I wouldn't be surprised to see stderr).  This is great for debugging if you start it manually.  You'll see all the log messages immediately in the terminal.

If you set up the entrypoint and manually start the container in interactive mode - same deal.  If you start it as a background container (pardon my vagueness), the output will be captured for `docker logs`.  It's the same technique favored by modern init systems like systemd (and the systemd "journal" logging system).

Once you have the daemon set up how you want, you may be interested in more customized systems for capturing logs, like the other answers.

**Docker has pluggable logging drivers, according to the manpage for `docker logs`.  There's a "syslog" driver which says it writes to the host syslog.**  It says `docker logs` won't work, but I don't expect that's a problem for you.

**WARNING**: `docker logs` does work if you use the journald logging driver.  However, on Debian defaults, my assumption is this would cause logs to be lost on reboot.  Because Debian doesn't set up a persistent journal.  It's not hard to change though, if that's what you want.

The other logging driver which supports the `docker logs` command is called "json-file".  I expect that's persistent, but you might prefer one of the other solutions.

### The "why" question

The point is that Docker containers don't necessarily work the same as the OS they're based on.  Docker isn't OS virtualization like `LXC`, `systemd-nspawn`, or a virtual machine.  Although Docker was derived from `LXC`, it was specifically designed for "application containers" that run a single program.

(Current) server distributions are designed as a combination of several running programs.  So you can't take a package from them and expect it to behave exactly the same way inside one of these application containers.

Communication with a logging daemon is a great example. There's nothing there that's going to change, except that people will become more familiar with the concept of application containers.  And whether that's what they actually want to use :).  I suspect a lot of sysadmins would be more interested in a mashup of LXC (OS containers), with something like NixOS to share packages between containers; it just hasn't been written yet AFAIK.  Or just a [better LXC](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/).

Comment: I started OpenVPN manually inside the container. The server is actually running but I can see no logs (`/var/log/syslog` is missing) inside the container.

Comment: As I say, that's expected behaviour.

Comment: Make sure you're not passing --daemon or --log, and you should see all log messages immediately in the terminal.

Comment: I run the container with the `--detach` and  the `--tty` parameters and I was expecting the logs to go to their default location `/var/log/syslog` inside the container.

Comment: I would like to achieve the default behavior I have on my host machine out of box. I just install the server and all logs go to the `syslog` by default. I want to have the logs inside the `/var/log/syslig` inside the container.

Comment: ... or inside the `/var/log/syslog` on the host machine.

Comment: For the first you would need the supervisord solution.  I think you can steal everything from the normal packaged scripts, but I haven't checked.  To match default behavior you will need a third service: cron, to run logrotate.

Comment: So your second suggestion seems very sensible - I editted the answer to mention a solution that should work.

Comment: Added to the end: a philosophical answer to your question about "default behaviour".

Comment: I've tried to use the `syslog` driver, but still no error messages are logged to the host's `syslog` when they usually *are* logged by the server running on the host machine. Anyways thanks for your assistance.